# Most efficient way to approximately double a cube with ruler and compass?

Tags: number-theory

It is known that doubling a cube with ruler and compass is not possible. And this is because $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructable. Mathologer visually demonstrates a proof of this in [1] for example. The obvious question then is, how close to this number can we get with ruler and compass? Is the answer arbitrarily close? How would we go about finding such a construction that gets to within $\epsilon$?

---

EDIT:
Since the answer to the first part of my question is "arbitrarily close", I'd like to ask what procedure gets within $\epsilon$ of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ in the least steps.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1sPvUr0YC0

Comment: Start with $5/4<\sqrt[3]{2}<63/50$ and iterate using the bisection method. Each term is rational, hence constructible, and the sequence converges, so we can achieve arbitrary precision (albeit somewhat slowly).

Comment: @Integrand, Newton's method is a rational method too but is much faster

Comment: @lhf I went for comfort, not speed ;)

Comment: Yes the obvious answer is "arbitrarily close". The more interesting question here is how to construct an approximate value, and how to improve on it to obtain arbritary accuracy, using a straight edge and compasses.

Comment: @sammygerbil - agree, edited the question.

Comment: Try to get a rational aproximation to $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and it is constructible. For example take    $\sqrt[3]{2}\approx\dfrac{1259922}{1000000}$ but it is not nice.

Comment: Right, but the field we can access with ruler and compass is larger than the rational field. Does this help make our procedure faster? Or not really?

Comment: There are an infinite number of ruler and compass approximations within $\epsilon$ which is the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

Remark: This answer was written when the question only asked if there was *some* construction that gets arbitrarily close to $\sqrt[3]2$ (but posted after the question was edited). The question as it now appears, asking for *efficient* constructions using the fewest ruler and compass steps, is much much harder. I'm leaving the rest of this answer as is, for what it's worth.

Suppose we start with two points $A$ and $B$. We would like to get construct points arbitrarily close to the point $Z$ on the line through $A$ and $B$ such that $B$ is between $A$ and $Z$ and $AZ:AB=\sqrt[3]2:1\approx1.259921:1$.

We start by drawing the line through $A$ and $B$ and then a circle centered at $B$ of radius $AB$, which produces a point $C$. Note that $B$ lies between $A$ and $C$ and $AC:AB=2:1\gt\sqrt[3]2:1$.

We can now *bisect* the line segment $\overline{BC}$ by drawing a circle centered at $C$ of radius $BC=AB$. This circle intersects the previous circle (from the previous paragraph) at two points $P$ and $Q$. Drawing the line through $P$ and $Q$, we obtain the midpoint of the line segment $\overline{BC}$. Call this point $D$.

We find that $AD:AB=1.5:1\gt\sqrt[3]2:1$, so we next bisect $BD$, obtaining the midpoint $E$, for which $AE:AB=1.25:1\lt\sqrt[3]2:1$.  The comparison tells us to bisect $ED$ next, obtaining a midpoint $F$ for which we find $AF:AB=1.375:1\gt\sqrt[3]2:1$. Successive bisections will, over time, eventually get us as close to the desired (but nonconstructible) point $Z$ as we like. The total number of steps in the construction is $O(|\log\epsilon|)$; roughly speaking, each bisection gives the next bit in the binary expansion of $\sqrt[3]2$, and each bisection takes either two or three new ruler-and-compass steps.

It might be of interest to see if there are *quicker* ways to construct two points, say $X$ and $Y$, such that $XY:AB\approx\sqrt[3]2:1$, where "quicker" is determined by the total number of circles and lines that need to be drawn, starting from the given points $A$ and $B$. There are certainly quicker *numerical* methods for approximating a cube root (e.g., Newton-Raphson), but it's not clear (to me, at least) how easily they translate into an efficient sequence of ruler and compass steps. Put differently, if you restrict yourself to a total of $N$ ruler and compass steps, what's the closest you can get to the cube root of $2$? It's conceivable that the best construction with $N+1$ steps is entirely different than the best construction with $N$ steps.

Comment: This does not provide the straight edge and compasses construction which was asked for. How can the comparison be made (using straight edge and compasses) between the ratio of lengths $AE:AB$ and the target value $ \sqrt[3]{2}$? It is necessary to know the exact value at each step of the construction - but that value is the unknown length which the construction aims to find.

Comment: @sammygerbil, I'm afraid I don't understand the nature of your objection. I am, in effect, doing a ruler-and-compass construction of rational numbers $p/q$; at each step of the way, one simply calculates the integer $p^3$ and the integer $2q^3$ to see which one is larger and thereby decide how to proceed with the next ruler-and-compass step. I suppose the arithmetic comparison could be carried out in a rulery-compassy way, but I hardly see the need to do so.

Comment: Unless that arithmetic comparison of $p^3$ and $2q^3$ is carried out with straight edge and compasses, it seems to me that it does not fulfill the requirements of the question. You seem to be suggesting that this step is trivial, but it seems to me far from trivial compared with the bisection steps which you have decribed in detail.

Comment: @sammygerbil, you can certainly construct a point $P$ on the line through $A$ and $B$ such that $AP:AB=p^3:1$, by marking off $p^3$ segments each of length equal to $AB$. Likewise you can construct a point $Q$ such that $AQ:AB=2q^3:1$. Then you just have to see how $AP$ compares to $AQ$. That'll tell you how $p/q$ compares to the cube root of $3$. More difficult might be to show a construction that determines whether a constructed point $C$ such that $AC:AB=(131\sqrt(2)-184):1$ lies between $A$ and $Z$ or not.

Comment: What you suggest (marking off $2q^3$ segments of length $AB$) is easy when $q^3$ is an integer, but in general it will not be. As Mathologer shows, there are ways of contructing products of arbitrary lengths, but these are less obvious than bisection.